# Docker linking works on one host but not another

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have two docker hosts, one for production and one for staging. They are, as far as I can tell, built exactly the same. They're running the same OS (Ubuntu) and the same build of Docker. I run a job via Jenkins which uses the linking feature in Docker.

On staging, it all works perfectly but on production, with exactly the same commands, if fails. They both use the same registry.

The commands are (doctored slightly for privacy)

```
docker run --detach --name bymysql --env=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password dockerdistro-staging:5000/mysql
docker run --link=bymysql -v /home/jenkins/data:/data dockerdistro-staging:5000/custom-container /command/we/run
```

With the staging version it all works fine but with production version I get the following error, generated by our own code which is looking for a mysql server on the standard port called bymysql.

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'bymysql' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'bymysql' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running on bymysql and that the port is 3306.
```

Given that it works fine on staging, I assume that the commands are fine and that there is some sort of difference in configuration with the host. But I don't know what would prevent the link feature from working.

Mystifyingly, if I run the same steps on the production box manually, rather than via Jenkins, it works on production too!

Output of docker version (same for both)

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Output of docker network inspect

- [gist](https://gist.github.com/simmogs/625c29b8dda3ef2a9fcfbcc67a4b6afb)

Comment: Can you post your `docker version` and `docker network inspect bridge` (you can censor out any containers listed) from each system?

Comment: Is it possible that the bymysql container has failed to start, and that's why the second container is failing to connect to it?

Comment: @VinceBowdren - I get a long hash back and no error message, so I think it's working ok. If I go in after at the command line, it's running.

Comment: @BMitch. Done. Thanks

Comment: You can rule out docker links and networking by running `docker run --link=bymysql -it --rm busybox ping bymysql`. If that comes back then the issue is most likely that mysql isn't listening or accepting connections on that port.

Comment: @BMitch Ping works

Comment: Do you only check for the db connection once or do you keep checking it on intervals?